# How can I sell my Android apps in a country that doesn't officially supported for merchants by Android-Market?

Tags: android, google-play

I can't sell my applications on Android-Market because my country is not supported for merchants.Is there any other market-place which let you to use paypal or is there any way to get around this problem ?

Edit:Question was not clear , edited to avoid missunderstanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few alternative markets:

- http://slideme.org/
- http://www.openmarket.co.za/
- http://andappstore.com

SlideMe looks more reliable from my perspective. Though they all are far not that popular as google android market.

Comment: You could also sell it yourself off your own site, just link to the .apk download for each sale. Thing to note is that both unofficial markets and straight .apk downloads need the user to allow "Unknown sources - Allow installation of non market apps" enabled in the phone's settings.

Answer (score 2):

There are literally dozens of Android markets.  I've been studying them for a few months (and blogging some of the details, but they're not all up yet).  Google is adding new paid locations regularly (check Wikipedia for the chart).  So... If you know of specific countries that you want to hit, research them specifically and find out what markets are big there. Many markets are specific to a region (for example the Chinese markets, some of which aren't even in English))

Slide me is available everywhere, but strangely most of my sales from them are still from the USA.  If you promote your app and direct people to SlideMe, however, you'll probably have decent results.

Comment: Can you give the mentioned link?

Comment: Here's the official link from Google showing where users can purchase apps: https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=138294  My blog is at http://ProjectJourneyman.com where I cover the app markets I've used.